# Como centralizar verticalmente um texto em uma div circular feita com shape-outside?

Tags: css

Tenho uma `div` > `span` que contém uma propriedade `shape-outside` que permite que um texto se ajuste dentro de um circulo.

Preciso que o texto se ajuste verticalmente ao centro, pois a cenários em que o texto é curto, mas em outros que o texto ocupa todo o circulo.

Tentei de todas as maneiras mas isso foge do meu intelecto rsrs.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/rafagets/pen/NWBqjro)

Answer (score 0):

Oie, você pode adicionar o seguinte CSS para a classe `circle`:

```css
...
.circle {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    ...
}
```

O atributo `align-items` permite centralizar verticalmente os elementos dentro de um elemento com `display: flex`.

Obs.: Para centralizar horizontalmente os elementos filhos de um elemento com
`display: flex` use `justify-content: center`